# Is there a drive time functionality in Excel 2016 similar to MapPoint?

Tags: excel, mappoint

I'm using the drive time zone functionality in Map Point a lot, but the software is no longer supported. I was wondering if it was possible to get similar functionality in Excel 2016, I've tried to replicate it in 3D Maps but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know if this can be done with Excel or any add ins?

Comment: Please explain the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Drive time zone, a polygon on the map showing a boundary that signifies the distance a driver could travel in X minutes in any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything like this in the Excel 3d Maps or PowerMaps.  We have been recommending our MapPoint customers move to Caliper's Maptitude product. Yes this does cost money (as did MapPoint, of course) but has more functionality than MapPoint, data is updated more frequently (and there is more of it), and they have a working, useful support service - more than can be said for Microsoft's support of MapPoint!

The latest versions do support drive time zones, and these can be created using the API. It supports the GIS concept of layers, so the drive time zones are 'drawn' as a polygon (area) layer. This can then be used to query/ manipulate other map layers as per any standard GIS.

(the API has a lot more methods/functions than MapPoint's API, and can be used via COM or Caliper's own macro language)

We've also ported some of our MapPoint products to Maptitude.

An alternative would be to roll your own (or pay someone like me to do it :-) ). If you do this, you would need a source of road data.

Comment: Yeah I've been looking at Caliper, it looks quite a bit better then MapPoint at this point. I'll try the free trial out and see what everyone thinks, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e84ec3a9-2ccc-4644-a2e2-70a471848ef8/drivetime-zone-using-bing-map-v8?forum=bingmaps It looks like Bing Maps no longer supports drivetime zones, and all Microsoft mapping is powered by this, so I'm thinking that an Excel option doesn't currently exist. If anyone finds something different that would be very helpful, but for now I'm going on the assumption that it doesn't exist.